# Samba Not able to access if wrong DNS is specified in Back to Back Connection

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, samba, internal-dns, server-message-block

We have 2 systems connected to each other through a LAN cable , so the connection here is BACK TO BACK , and it is not connected to a router or any outside node , it's just connected to each other through a LAN cable. One being the host and other being the node connected to the host. The host is able to create samba shared folders on it's local machine(host) , and the node connected to the host should be able to access the shared folder through the IP of the HOST

```
\\HOSTIP
```

Example

```
\\192.168.1.22
```

This is the setup and the requirement.

I have the following problem though. the shared folder created is able to access on the node when the DNS configuration in /etc/resolv.conf of the HOST is

```
 nameserver none
 nameserver none
```

or 
     nameserver anything_in_aplhabets
     nameserver anyting_in_alphabets

or 
     nameserver 127.0.0.1
     nameserver none

So the NODE is able to access the shared folder through samba with the following DNS configuration on the HOST machine.

But if I give any IP address like 192.168.1.77 or ANY IP addresss in my DNS configuration , I'm not able to access the shared folder through node through samba.

```
 nameserver 8.8.8.8
 nameserver 192.168.1.22
```

or 
     nameserver 192.168.1.1
     nameserver 192.168.1.20

So it's quite evident that it's not able to access samba because it tries to find the DNS server where IP is given and since it's a back to back connection , the IP is not reachable and the node cannot access the samba shared folder. My constraint here is , I want to keep the DNS servers IP intact , I do not wish to make the DNS to none or 127.0.0.1 . I want my DNS to be an IP address in format i.e 8.8.8.8 or 192.168.1.22 , in short I wish to keep the IP addresss in /etc/resolv.conf setting and want to access the Shared Folder through Node .

What is the Configuration in SAMBA for this to be achieved ? Please help me.

Comment: As the server and node are both are offline, try with local static DNS in `/etc/hosts` on your node ex.: `192.168.1.22 MYSERVER`. This tells your node, that MYSERVER is located at 192.168.1.22 .